# Отрисовка круга из двух изображений и анимация сектора круга

Tags: анимация, javascript, кроссбраузерность

Есть 2 изображения в виде круга, например, в формате png.
Необходимо нарисовать круг на web-странице, чтобы был виден сектор первого изображения (угол сектора задаётся, может изменяться), а остальная часть круга(оставшийся сектор) - из второго изображения.

Как такое можно реализовать? Как анимировать? Анимация, когда мы задаём, что угол сектора должен измениться, например, увеличиться на 50 градусов и он плавно увеличивается.

Немаловажна кроссбраузерность.

@invincible, конкретизирую: [пример](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69Db9.gif)

Надо, чтобы фиолетовая часть (сектор) могла уменьшаться, а жёлтая увеличиваться и наоборот.

Comment: Не очень хочется переписывать велосипед, поэтому посмотрите примеры ниже, а если будут вопросы пишите.
Пример 1: http://raphaeljs.com/polar-clock.html
Пример 2: http://raphaeljs.com/growing-pie.html
Пример 3: http://raphaeljs.com/pie.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Рафаэль](http://raphaeljs.com) - Вам в помощь. Не очень понял задачу, если сделаете иллюстрацию, возможно помогу с конкретным кодом, или смотрите примеры на сайте и в инете.

Comment: да, мне тоже кажется что векрторная графика тут лучше подойдет , чем изврат с картинками =)

Comment: Согласен. Но замечу, что RaphaelJS позволяет также манипулировать и изображениями, работая с ними как с объектами + такие бонусы, как обрезка, вращения, маска и т.п.

Comment: А как обрезать изображение?

Comment: Ну, примерно так: http://jsfiddle.net/invincible/J9LeL/